# Location of persistence.xml in appengine-skeleton-archetype

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, jpa

Where is the place of **persistence.xml** in *appengine-skeleton-archetype*?

Comment: you mean apart from under META-INF/ ? (i.e where it is on every JPA application)

Comment: I know it should be in META-INF, but I don't know where to put this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [Google App Engine Documentation for JPA](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Setting_Up_JPA_2_0):

"**Creating the persistence.xml File**

The JPA interface needs a configuration file named persistence.xml in the application's `war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/` directory. You can create this file in this location directly, or have your build process copy this file from a source directory."

This is a little confusing, because the [Google App Engine Maven project setup/structure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#creating_app_engine_applications_or_backend_apis_using_the_archetypes) is defined as such:

```
$ tree myapp
myapp
    eclipse-launch-profiles
        DevAppServer.launch
        UpdateApplication.launch
    nbactions.xml
    pom.xml
    README.md
    src
        main
            java
            webapp
                WEB-INF
                    appengine-web.xml
                    logging.properties
                    web.xml
        test
    target
```

But in any case, the `war` directory and the `webapp` directory should be interchangable.

Comment: It works, thanks. I just want to point that @Albertoimpl's answer was also helpful.

Comment: adding folder "src/main/resources/META-INF" via build path as mentioned @Albertoimpl creates META-INF in "Java Resources/src/main/resources" which is copied by eclipse into right directory "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes".

Answer (score 2):

Just place it in the META-INF folder, create it inside "myapp/src/main"

1. Right clicking the Project File -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Add the folder META-INF to the build path
3. Maven -> Update Project

[image: This is an example with the archetype]